# How to change perspective projection to orthographic projection in openGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es, qt4, opengl-3

I am working on a CAD application. I have a requirement of changing a projection on clicking of a button.

I implemented it successfully but after changing the projection from perspective to orthographic,the object dimension becomes changed.

So how can I implement this scenario so that object dimension becomes unchanged?

I switched between `glOrtho()` and `glPerspective()` to change the projection.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the dimension changes, and what you mean with "unchanged?"

Comment: When switching you can only assure that only one "slice" of the frustum will remain unchanged. The rest of the slices will become scaled up or down.

Comment: the dimension change is called perspective distortion and is expected to happen.